# DB2 query to fetch first value in a group

Tags: db2

I have a db2 query which has to fetch the first value present for a column(Col6). I have tried using minimum for the column, but it fetches the first value in ascending order.

The table is as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv
10      -1      N/A     1       10      Fl Sales
10      -1      N/A     1       10      St Ss Bu
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv
```

The expected output for Col7 is as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6        Col7
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv    Pack Inv
10      -1      N/A     1       10      Fl Sales    Pack Inv
10      -1      N/A     1       10      St Ss Bu    Pack Inv
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv    Pack Inv
```

By using MIN(Col6) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1) AS "Col7",the output generated is:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6        Col7
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv    Fl Sales
10      -1      N/A     1       10      Fl Sales    Fl Sales
10      -1      N/A     1       10      St Ss Bu    Fl Sales
10      -1      N/A     1       41      Pack Inv    Fl Sales
```

May I know how the expected output can be achieved in db2.

Thank you

Comment: "First" based on what sequence? What column determines the desired order within a set of rows for a particular Col1 value?  If you don't specify the order, DB2 will not guarantee the sequencing of the rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not clear how the "first" column is defined in your data, this general problem is solved by ranking columns with `row_number()` and then selecting the first one:

```
with ranked as (
  select col1,
         col6,
         row_number() over (partition by col1 order by [cols that define "first"]) rank
)
select col1, col6 from ranked where rank=1
```

You can then join this result back to the original table if you want to add the selected value to every row...or use `merge` to insert it as a new column if that is what you are after.