# Question with SQL query on a table with all columns returned for a unique column value

Tags: sql, db2

Let say I have a table MyTable with DriverNum, DriverName, Comment, DateComment, AccNum columns. And MyTable has 3 records with DriverNum values of 1, 2, 2.

Database is IBMDB2.

I can get a unique result of DriverNum values as 1 and 2 with below SQL query. (1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT DriverNum 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE AccNum = '12345' AND DateComment = 'SomeDate'
```

It should be ordered by DateComment timestamp as I try to apply the below SQL query (2) to the query result from (1) but I don't know how to do the JOIN SQL

```
select *
from MyTable
WHERE AccNum = '12345' AND DriverNum =?
ORDER BY DateComment DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Optionally, I can run java codes for query_result_1 from (1) and applying sql query from (2) and get the result like below.

for (int lDrvNum : query_result_1)
{
select *
from MyTable
WHERE AccNum = '12345' AND DriverNum = lDrvNum
ORDER BY DateComment DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
}

I wonder if I can combine queries from (1) & (2) into a single query to achieve my gold? Please help as I am stuck on this.

Thank you for your help and SORRY that I am not good with SQL language. Kenny

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data, expected output and your specific DBMS tag?

Comment: Look into `row_number over (partition by... order by...)`.

Comment: This question is asked and answered literally thousands of times. If you TAG your specific RDBMS (as the *sql* tag description recommends) someone can point you to a suitable answer either on Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I did tried search similar questions but could not find similar to my need for this. :--(. I am pretty new here and will learn to improve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 query to fetch first value in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238575/db2-query-to-fetch-first-value-in-a-group)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first row from each subgroup according to a specific ordering by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(
      partition by drivernum    -- this separates the subgroups
      order by datecomment desc -- this defines which one is the first row
    ) as rn
  from MyTable t
  WHERE AccNum = '12345' AND DateComment = 'SomeDate'
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks and May I ask what is t refers to ? Do I have to declare MyTable as t? Thx.

Comment: `t` is just a one-letter alias of `MyTable`. Just a shorthand to write queries. If you omit it in line #8, then you'll need to type `MyTable.*` in line #3.

Comment: Just wonder how what t is refers to and how can I apply the WHERE clause like (WHERE AccNum = '12345' AND DriverNum =?) Thx

Comment: It is working now :--) Awesome. I just putr the WHERE clause right after MyTable t. Thanks The Impaler and all for helping. :--)

Comment: Again, Thank you all for your helps.